# Get Triggers from Version Enabled Table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, versioning, workspace

I am new to Oracle Workspace Manager. I have a trigger that fills my IDs every time i insert a record. I created the trigger before I enable the versioning of my table. 
After versioning was enabled in my table, I can no longer find my trigger but have these triggers instead:

```
OVM_DELETE_7
OVM_INSERT_7
OVM_UPDATE_7
```

What I wanted to do is Query the triggers that I created on my tables. Is there a way to do that without disabling the versioning on my table? I have too many versioned-enabled tables and that would be a hassle disabling the version in every table just for that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of triggers created on a version-enabled tables that you(current user) owns, you can query `USER_WM_TAB_TRIGGERS` view or `ALL_WM_TAB_TRIGGERS` view (if you've been granted `create any trigger` privilege) to get information about triggers for all version-enabled tables.